# OpenCL char limit

Tags: c++, opencl, opencl-c++

both of the implementations of `printsomestuff` will only write up to res[7] (i.e.: `WORLD!\0` or `!ELLOWO\0`)

main.cpp:

```
...
char A[16] = "HELLO ";
        cl::Buffer aBuf(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(A));

        char B[16] = "WORLD!";
        cl::Buffer bBuf(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(B));

        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(aBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(A) * sizeof(char), A);
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(bBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(B) * sizeof(char), B);

        char res[16];
        cl::Buffer resBuf(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(res) * sizeof(char));

        cl::Kernel kernel(program, "printsomestuff");
        kernel.setArg(0, aBuf);
        kernel.setArg(1, bBuf);
        kernel.setArg(2, resBuf);

        queue.enqueueTask(kernel);
        //queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(32), cl::NullRange);

        queue.enqueueReadBuffer(resBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(resBuf), res);

        std::cout << res;
...
```

my_kernels.cl

```
kernel void printsomestuff(__global char *A, __global char *B,
                           __global char *res) {

  /*  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      res[i] = B[i];
      res[i + 8] = A[i];
    }*/

  res[0] = '!';
  res[1] = 'E';
  res[2] = 'L';
  res[3] = 'L';
  res[4] = 'O';
  res[5] = ' ';
  res[6] = 'W';
  res[7] = 'O';
  res[8] = 'R';
  res[9] = 'L';
  res[10] = 'D';
  res[11] = '!';
  res[12] = '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(A)` when `A` is a `char*` is the size of the pointer, not the length of the array. So, if you pass your `char A[16]` to this function:

```
kernel void printsomestuff(__global char *A, __global char *B,
                           __global char *res) {
```

`sizeof(A)` will be the size of a pointer which is usually 4 or 8 `char`s. It has no knowledge of the length.

[Demo 1](https://godbolt.org/z/GaP4P7)

You need to provide the size as a separate parameter or use a type created for carrying data of this type, like a `std::string`.

If you only have fixed sized `char` arrays, you could make some adjustment to your functions to make them preserve the array extent, like this:

```
template<std::size_t Asize, std::size_t Bsize, std::size_t Ressize>
kernel void printsomestuff(__global char (&A)[Asize], __global char (&B)[Bsize],
                           __global char (&res)[Ressize]) {
```

<sup>(I don't really know what `__global` does but I'll leave it in)</sup>

You now have all sizes you need to use in the function.
[Demo 2](https://godbolt.org/z/4Y35bK)

Comment: Thank you Ted, it was actually res that was too small: "queue.enqueueReadBuffer(resBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, 16, res);" works

Comment: @lemmer Great, but try to avoid hardcoding sizes. It'll be hard to remember all places if you change anything later.

Comment: Regarding `__global`, see [OpenCL When to use global, private, local, constant adress spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45426212/673852)

Comment: @Ruslan Whoa, that's a lot to read. :-) TL;DR; Should I put it back?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether this will work with references. Might be better to pass them as pointers to arrays instead. (I've not used OpenCL myself)

Comment: @Ruslan Hmm, if I change it to `void printsomestuff(__global char (*A)[Asize], __global char (*B)[Bsize], __global char (*res)[Ressize])` it would be necessary to call the function with `&A, &B, &res`. Well... let's hear what OP has to say about it. It's probably possible to keep the array extent _somehow_ when using `__global` so I'll adjust it accordingly.

Comment: @lemmer Can you clear this `__global` thing up? Does it work with references as I've now done it in the answer or does it need to be pointers?